# Parse Core data Alternate?

Tags: parsing, core-data, onesignal

I am currently hosting my app on Parse and it contains core data. As parse is shutting down in few day .Can you suggest me better solution where I can host my database and push notification functionality as well ?I read about one signal ? can I host database there?

Answer (score 0):

I work for [Buddy Platform](https://buddy.com), and we offer [Parse on Buddy](https://buddy.com/parse), a great hosted Parse Server solution.

We provide fully scalable, highly-available hosting with full regular backups, monitoring, etc. for all apps. We offer enterprise-level status with great documentation, support, & continued new development, for migration and beyond. All at the same price as the current Parse service!

We've improved the push notifications support to handle sending to millions of both iOS and Android devices, in addition to filling in missing functionality in the open-source Parse Server. Migrating is a simple process, please check out our documentation.

Buddy is a public company with international offices, and has been serving the mobile-backend-as-a-service space since 2011.